# Looking for matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

My problem is as follows:

I have the followings matrices:

```
  0 1
  1 1
```

or

```
  1 1 1
  1 1 1 
  0 1 0
```

or

```
  1 1 1 0
  1 1 1 1
  0 1 1 0
```

And I want to get the following matrices:

```
  0 1
  2 1
```

or

```
  1 1 1
  1 1 1 
  0 2 0
```

or

```
  1 1 1 0
  1 1 1 2
  0 3 3 0
```

What I want is to get the submatrices (or col-vector, or row-vector in case that submatrices are not possible) as large as possible.

I am going to explain clearly:

If the input is the third matrix:

```
  1 1 1 0
  1 1 1 1
  0 1 1 0
```

I want to group elements vertically or horizontally, making these submatrices as large as possible. The largest submatrix in this example is:

```
  x x x 0
  x x x 1
  0 1 1 0
```

Another possible submatrix, that is also largest is:

```
  1 x x 0
  1 x x 1
  0 x x 0
```

Both represented by `x`.

Then, there are three elements with 1, yet. So I want to group again. Getting the largest submatrices (or sub-vector) again. At that point, depending on the previous move, we will get:

```
  x x x 0
  x x x 1
  0 y y 0
```

or

```
  y x x 0
  y x x 1
  0 x x 0
```

Represented by `y`.

Now, we have another element, that has not being grouped, and now we make another group (represented by `z`):

```
  y x x 0
  y x x z
  0 x x 0
```

If now we choose another input, we have the following steps:

```
  0 1
  1 1
```

We have two sub-vector, so we have two possible solutions:

```
  0 1
  x x
```

or

```
  0 x
  1 x
```

And then, depending on the solution chosen, we have the following solution:

```
  0 y
  x x
```

or

```
  0 x
  y x
```

Grouping the other element alone.

Finally, in the second case, we only have one possible solution:

```
  1 1 1
  1 1 1 
  0 1 0
```

Getting the largest submatrix we have this solution:

```
  x x x
  x x x
  0 1 0
```

And then, group the last element alone:

```
  x x x
  x x x
  0 y 0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lets delete all the comments as they are just noise now.

Comment: This is an optimization problem. You want "the best" possible solution or a solution "good enough"? Since the approach to make an optimal or suboptimal solution might be very different

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It doesn't matter, it isn't an optimization problem. What I want is to find submatrices as biggest as possible, until cluster or group all the elements equal to 1. Thank you. There aren't "best" or "good enough" solutions, there are "possible solutions"

Comment: Something like [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481868/largest-rectangle-of-1s-in-2d-binary-matrix)?

Comment: It is definitely an optimization problem, for which you will need to create a tree and explore it. And if you have big complex matrices the problem will get difficult enough so it might be unfeasible to get optimal solutions. This is why I was asking if "good enough" solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be fast, but brute forcing your way through would work (for small problems). Pseudo code like:

```
A = [1, 0; 1, 1];
B = zeros(size(A));
bCount = 1;
while any(A ~= 0)
globalmax = 0;
for i,j = 1 : sizeOfMatrix
    localmax = 0;
    for ii,jj = i,j : sizeOfMatrix
       if ((ii-i+1) * (jj-j+1) > localmax ... &&
          && all(A(i:ii, j:jj) ~= 0))
          localmax = (ii-i+1) * (jj-j+1);
          localmaxPoints = [i, ii; j, jj];
       end
    end
    if (localmax > globalmax)
       globalmax = localmax;
       globalmaxPoints = localmaxPoints;
    end
end
A[globalmaxPoints] = 0;
B[globalmaxPoints] = bCount;
bCount = bCount+1;
end
```

Note this code won't work directly, but it should be easy to fix it.
Obviously the approach it is suitable only for small matrices - too slow for anything large. There are some small optimizations which are trivial, but won't change much.

You require something better to find optimum for a huge matrix. Unless you have some properties in these matrices you could use (for example zeros are only along the edges), you will have to use optimization techniques. You might not get the most optimal solution, but it will be a very good one.