# how to find a submatrix with primes in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, primes, submatrix

```
Enter n: 3
Enter range: 50  // range of prime numbers



A =  1 12 37 
     24 45 11
     2  34 10

matrix sum = 48

solution submatrix = 37   //largest rectangle of primes
                     11


coordinates are= 1 3 2 3
```

First program gives a random matrix and finds largest rectangle consists of primes(submatrix) and then displaying their sum and coordiantes.

how can i write a program like this in matlab?

Comment: have you tried something at least?

Comment: Also, your question is very unclear. It's hard to guess what you want

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but im freshman just learning the basic it would mean a lot if you could help me out.

Comment: Use `isprime` to find which matrix elements are prime, then your question becomes finding the largest rectangle of 1's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481868/largest-rectangle-of-1s-in-2d-binary-matrix

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking at a 3 x 3 matrix:

```
 1 12 37
24 45 11
 2 34 10
```

Start by finding all the prime numbers in the matrix.  In this case 37, 11, 2.

Quite what you want to do then is not clear from your question.  Do you want a submatrix with those three number and others or do you want submatrices with all prime numbers?

It is not clear where you get the sum of 48 from.  37 + 11 = 48, but that leaves out the prime 2.  The sum on the three primes is 50.

You need to clarify your question if you want more help.